# Git: Check diff between local copy and HEAD with different path

Tags: git, diff

File situation:
TheTree/Archive/.git
TheTree/Archive/local_copy_of_git_repository_files
TheTree/Another_copy_of_git_repository_files

We run a Software which implement git for revision handling in very simple way ( No branches ... ) The local copy of files from git are stored to "TheTree/Archive". Then these file additionally copied to "TheTree" which are finaly used by the Software. We do not know which version in "TheTree" is currently checked out from git.
I need to know:

1. Is the copy in "TheTree" is changed against HEAD?
2. Which SHA1 Key ( verion in git ) is matching the "TheTree" files?

I know the I have to use git diff and git log But I do not know how to handle files in a path which are not controled by git ( TheTree ).

Comment: `git diff` can compare two "non-git" paths. Does `git diff TheTree/Archive/local_copy_of_git_repository_files TheTree/Another_copy_of_git_repository_files` do the trick?

Comment: Check the `--no-index` option for `git diff` files outside of git. The doc is [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgt--no-index--ltpathgtltpathgt).